# How do I load FastText pretrained model with Gensim?

Tags: nlp, gensim

I tried to load fastText pretrained model from here [Fasttext model](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/blob/master/pretrained-vectors.md). I am using [wiki.simple.en](https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/fasttext-vectors/wiki.simple.zip)

```
from gensim.models.keyedvectors import KeyedVectors

word_vectors = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('wiki.simple.bin', binary=True)
```

But, it shows the following errors

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nltk_check.py", line 28, in <module>
    word_vectors = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('wiki.simple.bin', binary=True)
  File "P:\major_project\venv\lib\sitepackages\gensim\models\keyedvectors.py",line 206, in load_word2vec_format
     header = utils.to_unicode(fin.readline(), encoding=encoding)
  File "P:\major_project\venv\lib\site-packages\gensim\utils.py", line 235, in any2unicode
    return unicode(text, encoding, errors=errors)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xba in position 0: invalid start byte
```

**Question 1** How do I load fasttext model with Gensim?

**Question 2** Also, after loading the model, I want to find the similarity between two words

```py
 model.find_similarity('teacher', 'teaches')
 # Something like this
 Output : 0.99
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Is gensim an absolute requirement? In the end, I just wound up going with the `fasttext` library directly, since I really just needed the words to get transformed

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here's the link for the methods available for fasttext implementation in gensim [fasttext.py](https://github.com/piskvorky/gensim/blob/develop/gensim/models/wrappers/fasttext.py)

```py
from gensim.models.wrappers import FastText

model = FastText.load_fasttext_format('wiki.simple')

print(model.most_similar('teacher'))
# Output = [('headteacher', 0.8075869083404541), ('schoolteacher', 0.7955552339553833), ('teachers', 0.733420729637146), ('teaches', 0.6839243173599243), ('meacher', 0.6825737357139587), ('teach', 0.6285147070884705), ('taught', 0.6244685649871826), ('teaching', 0.6199781894683838), ('schoolmaster', 0.6037642955780029), ('lessons', 0.5812176465988159)]

print(model.similarity('teacher', 'teaches'))
# Output = 0.683924396754
```

Comment: I get ```DeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated `load_fasttext_format` (use load_facebook_vectors```. So I am using  ```from gensim.models.fasttext import load_facebook_model ```

Comment: @Sabbiu, could you please specify the model you used? I'm receiving `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gensim.models.wrappers'` from Gensim version 4.1.1.

Answer (score 16):

For **.bin** use: [`load_fasttext_format()`](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/fasttext.html#gensim.models.fasttext.FastText.load_fasttext_format) (this typically contains full model with parameters, ngrams, etc).

For **.vec** use: [`load_word2vec_format`](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/keyedvectors.html#gensim.models.keyedvectors.Word2VecKeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format) (this contains ONLY word-vectors -> no ngrams + you can't update an model).

**Note**:: If you are facing issues with the memory or you are not able to load .bin models, then check the [pyfasttext](https://pypi.org/project/pyfasttext/) model for the same.

Credits : Ivan Menshikh (Gensim Maintainer)

Comment: "For .bin.... you can continue training after loading."

This is not true, as documentation states: "Due to limitations in the FastText API, you cannot continue training with a model loaded this way."

https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/fasttext.html#gensim.models.fasttext.FastText.load_fasttext_format

Comment: This is no longer true:
DeprecationWarning: Deprecated. Use gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format instead.

Comment: @mickythump Can you please suggest some edits here?

Answer (score 10):

**Update 04/2020**

[`load_fasttext_format()`](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/fasttext.html#gensim.models.fasttext.FastText.load_fasttext_format) is now deprecated, the updated way is to load the models is with [`gensim.models.fasttext.load_facebook_model()`](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/fasttext.html#gensim.models.fasttext.load_facebook_model) or [`gensim.models.fasttext.load_facebook_vectors()`](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/fasttext.html#gensim.models.fasttext.load_facebook_vectors) for binaries and vecs respectively.

For example:

```
from gensim.models.fasttext import load_facebook_model

wv = load_facebook_model('<path_to.bin.gz>')
```

Comment: It is the .bin file, not the .gz file

Comment: `models.fasttext.load_facebook_vectors(path)` can read a .bin.gz file at present

Comment: Good to know, thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 5):

I really wanted to use gensim, but ultimately found that using the native `fasttext` library worked out better for me. The following code you can copy/paste into google colab and will work, out of the box:

`pip install fasttext`

```
import fasttext.util
fasttext.util.download_model('en', if_exists='ignore')  # English
ft = fasttext.load_model('cc.en.300.bin')
```

Works for out of vocab words too:

```
ft.get_word_vector("another")
ft.get_word_vector("dkjeri37id20hnd")
```

Comment: but how to load this BIN file for the embedding layer of keras NN?

Comment: I have found a way! I used .vec file and loaded it.

Answer (score 2):

The FastText binary format (which is what it looks like you're trying to load) isn't compatible with Gensim's `word2vec` format; the former contains additional information about subword units, which `word2vec` doesn't make use of.

There's some discussion of the issue (and a workaround), on the FastText Github page. In short, you'll have to load the text format (available at https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/blob/master/pretrained-vectors.md).

Once you've loaded the text format, you can use Gensim to save it in binary format, which will dramatically reduce the model size, and speed up future loading.

https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/issues/171#issuecomment-294295302

Answer (score 0):

Let’s use a pre-trained model rather than training our own word embeddings.
For this, you can download pre-trained vectors from [here](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/english-vectors.html).
Each line of this file contains a word and it’s a corresponding n-dimensional vector. We will create a dictionary using this file for mapping each word to its vector representation.

```
from gensim.models import FastText
def load_fasttext():
        print('loading word embeddings...')
        embeddings_index = {}
        f = open('../input/fasttext/wiki.simple.vec',encoding='utf-8')
        for line in tqdm(f):
        values = line.strip().rsplit(' ')
        word = values[0]
        coefs = np.asarray(values[1:], dtype='float32')
        embeddings_index[word] = coefs
        f.close()
        print('found %s word vectors' % len(embeddings_index))
    
        return embeddings_index

embeddings_index=load_fastext()
```

[image]

Let’s check the embedding for a word,

[image]

```
embeddings_index['london'].shape
```

Here’s a bit more info, from a blog post I wrote for my company, on [FastText](https://neptune.ai/blog/document-classification-small-datasets?utm_source=stackexchange&utm_medium=answer&utm_campaign=blog-document-classification-small-datasets) and other document classification methods (for smaller datasets)