# Fasttext error while loading wiki pre-trained data

Tags: python, word2vec, gensim

I am loading the model using gensim package this way:

```
from gensim.models import FastText
model = FastText.load_fasttext_format('wiki-news-300d-1M-subword.bin')
```

as stated [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/20071/how-do-i-load-fasttext-pretrained-model-with-gensim).

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe6 in position 57: unexpected end of data
```

The .bin file is downloaded from this [source](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/issues/656).

How to load the model correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `load_model` method instead of `load_fasstext_format` method. Also, you could `FastText` Library directly without really having to install `gensim` to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

The first answer is good but might make you confused. Those two steps should be implemented together.

See this link: https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/2378#issuecomment-791999124

However fasttext package does not have the 'similarity' module, you can add the scipy way in case you need.

```
import fasttext
from scipy import spatial

model = fasttext.load_model('wiki-news-300d-1M-subword.bin')

print(model['teacher'])
print(model['teaches'])

result = 1 - spatial.distance.cosine(model['teacher'], model['headteacher'])
print(result)
```